# Source for the lion as a symbol for divine judgement?

Tags: animals, symbols-symbology

I recall hearing that the lion symbolically represents Middat haDin, the attribute of divine justice, but I don't know of a source for this idea.

Is there a source which states that the lion is a symbol for divine judgment?

Answer (score 7):

[Deuteronomy 33:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.33.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וּלְדָ֣ן אָמַ֔ר דָּ֖ן גּ֣וּר אַרְיֵ֑ה יְזַנֵּ֖ק מִן־הַבָּשָֽׁן׃
>
> And of Dan he said: Dan is a lion’s whelp That leaps forth from Bashan.

**[Rabbeinu Bachya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher)** writes  [**in his commentary**](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Devarim.33.22.1-2?lang=bi) to that *pasuk*:

> **דן גור אריה**. ע"ד הפשט, המשילו בגבורה לגור אריה כאשר הוא מדלג מהר בשן
>   . דן גור אריה, 
>   וע"ד הקבלה נקרא דן כנגד מדת הדין, כי כן אמרה רחל עליו (בראשית ל׳:ו׳) דנני אלהים, **והמשילו משה בברכתו לגור אריה כנגד מדת הדין של מעלה ששם צורת גור אריה**, וזה מבואר.
>
> **Dan is a lion cub**. According to the plain meaning of the text Moses compares Dan’s bravery and physical strength to that of a lion, describing how he leaps down from the mountain of Bashan.
>
> A kabbalistic approach: the tribe was called Dan, corresponding to the attribute of Justice. When the original Dan was born his step-mother Rachel had said that G’d had judged her (Genesis 30,6). **The reason Moses compared the tribe of Dan in his blessing to a lion was that the celestial image of the attribute of Justice is that of a lion cub**.

Comment: Note, that ארי"ה has the same numerical value as גבור"ה.